# What is this game called?

Tags: game-identification, snes

[image]

I guess it's a SNES game, but I don't know the name.
Google reverse has failed me. Nothing.
Please help me.

Comment: You only added a picture. Tell us more about this game. If you owned it, you should remember gameplay. If you found the image; you could have clicked on the link.

Comment: It looks like it *might* be Chrono Trigger, but without more information I can't say

Comment: @RookieTEC9 - Asking about identifying a game from memory is off-topic anyway, and the image could also have been screencapped from a video, perhaps a channel's intro sequence? Either way, I agree we need the context behind the image as a starting point. @ askahkuwestion - where did you get the image?

Comment: @RookieTEC9 And not just a picture, but a picture of background graphics that could literally be from any of several SNES games.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

At a guess, it's [Terranigma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terranigma).

This is a picture of Terranigma [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terranigma#/media/File:Terranigma_screenshot_adventure_battle.jpg) that appears to be the same area (the towers near the game's beginning):

[image: Ark fights enemies in the first dungeon area]

Comment: If it's not Terranigma, it's likely one of the other two games in the same "series:" Soulblazer or Illusion of Gaia.  Quintet tended to share assets between its games.

Comment: That's the same guess I would have made.

Comment: This is the game. You can see the location that the screenshot is at [here](https://youtu.be/LyFg4l0_mOc?t=11m19s)

Comment: @Ktash I was originally going to say it was probably the towers or one of the castles, but once I found the screenshot I just assumed it was one of the towers (Tower 4 specifically).  Whoops. (Although the Portrait frames did make me think it might be the castle in Spain.)